# Remove visual filter context on dates but keep slicer filters on

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two tables like this

[image]

I am trying to get NAV of the first date (in the selected dates). I tried multiple ways but couldn't get it. Here are a couple of expressions I tried. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
NAV First Date = CALCULATE(MIN(FundNAV[NAV]),ALLEXCEPT(FundNAV,FundNAV[Fund Name]),FIRSTDATE(Dates[Date]))


NAV First Date = CALCULATE(MIN(FundNAV[NAV]),FILTER(ALL(Dates[Date]),Dates[Date]=MIN(Dates[Date])))
```

[image]

I got it working with the below measure, but have a bug in the expression. As you can see for the third fund there is no record on the selected first date, so it's returning blank, ideally, it should return the next available NAV for all remaining days.

```
NAV First Date = VAR frist_date = CALCULATE ( FIRSTDATE( Dates[Date] ),ALLSELECTED(FundNAV),VALUES(FundNAV[Fund Name]))
        RETURN CALCULATE(MIN(FundNAV[NAV]),Dates[Date]=frist_date)
```

[image]

Comment: Try Dates[Date] >= frist_date in stead of Dates[Date]=frist_date

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
NAV First Date =
VAR mindate =
    CALCULATE ( MIN ( FundNAV[NAV Date] ), ALLSELECTED ( Dates[Date] ) )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( MIN ( FundNAV[NAV] ), ALL(FundNAV[NAV Date]), FundNAV[NAV Date] = mindate )
```

This measure first calculated the minimum FundNAV[NAV Date], within the selected dates from the Dates tabel. Then it returns the FundNAV[NAV] for that date.

Comment: this is partially working, please find the screenshot updated to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Please test below 2 measures. I think Both will solve your problems:

```
NAV First Date =
CALCULATE ( MIN ( FundNAV[NAV] ), ALL ( FundNAV[Fund Name]), ALL ( Dates[Date] ) )
```

and This one uses the entire fact table as filter. (Expanded tables logic. it also removes any filter on dates)

```
NAV First Date =
CALCULATE ( MIN ( FundNAV[NAV] ), ALL ( FundNAV ) )
```

Comment: thanks for your quick answer. I tried both measures, they removed date and fund filter completely.  uploaded screenshot to the question.

Comment: OK. Not solved!!! Now please add this as 3rd filter: Dates[Date] = MIN(Dates[Date])

Comment: or this one is better, I think. NAV First Date =
CALCULATE ( MIN ( FundNAV[NAV] ), ALL ( FundNAV ) , FIRSTDATE(Dates[Date]))

Comment: Thanks for providing more options, this is still not working, it's getting me the first date of the entire dataset, it's not taking in external filters.

Comment: Please try this one: NAV First Date = CALCULATE ( MIN ( FundNAV[NAV] ), ALL ( FundNAV ), FILTER(Dates, Dates[Date) = MIN(Dates[Date]))

Comment: Sorry Sen, this didn't work too.

Comment: please see my new edits to the post, I have got it working but there is a bug.